# PowerPoint - Getting the original Shape from inside a Placeholder (programatically)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'll give an example with a SmartArt Shape, but it could be asked about other shapes too.

When I go over `Slide.Shapes`, one of the Shapes has:

`Shape.Type=msoPlaceholder` and `Shape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType=msoSmartArt`

Is there a way to get to the actual SmartArt Shape contained in the placeholder?

Comment: Not in PowerPoint 2007, but in PowerPoint 2010 - yes. Use `SmartArtQuickStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

Late but in case anyone looks for an answer to this later:

On approach is to copy the placeholder shape.  The copy will be a duplicate of whatever the .ContainedType of the placeholder was, not a placeholder itself.

This works in 2007 as well, btw.